# using repeater with entity framework in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i am using repeater in entity framework.I want to display all items in database and select one of them and send it to another page.I get all items from database without a problem but i can't get it to another page.This is my repeater code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeatersearch" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <li>
                    <div class="product">
                        <a class="info">                            
                            <span class="holder">
                                <img id="Image1" src="PerfumeImages/<%#Eval("Image") %>" />
                                <span class="book-name">
                                    <%#Eval("Name") %><br />
                                </span>                                 
                                <span class="description">
                                     <%#Eval("CGender") %><br />
                                     <%#Eval("Size") %> ml<br />
                                     <%#Eval("Stock") %> stock left<br />
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="buy-btn"><asp:Button ID="btnProduct1Addtocart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" onClick="btn_addCart" /><span class="price"> <%#Eval("Price") %><span class="low">TL</span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>                        
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

i want to send values to Detailed.aspx page when the user clicked button.Here is code of my button.

```
protected void btn_addCart(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Response.Redirect("~/Detailed.aspx?Id="?????? ");
    }
```

I dont know what should i write to place which i showed with question marks.And this is my code from the receiver page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to send a productId to the other page and get your required info from your database using the productId

Comment: I can take it with  <%#Eval("Id") %> but i dont know how can i send to other page @AliShahrokhi

Comment: just put the code for you @user3173750

Answer (score 0):

First change your button to this. It adds `CommandName` (which in this case is purely optional) and `CommandArgument` to hold the `id`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProduct1Addtocart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" onClick="btn_addCart" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("CGender") %>" />
```

Then in the code behind, in your button click handler:

```
protected void btn_addCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    if (btn.CommandName == "AddToCart")
    {
        //Now you have the id to use in your code here
        var id = btn.CommandArgument;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only require to go to another page for a single item click you just need to use the required url in your repeater control as below:

```
     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeatersearch" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <li>
           <div class="product" >
              <a class="info" href='<%: ResolveUrl("~/Detaild.aspx?Id=" + Eval("Id"))%>'>             
                        //the rest of your code...
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>                        
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```